# Check the inner type of FieldAlias in jOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

Is it possible to check the wrapped type of alias field in jOOQ? Something like `field.getWrapped() instanceof AggregateFunction`.

Also, I see that the class `FieldAlias` is not public, so it's not even possible to check `field instanceof FieldAlias`. What was the motivation for making this class not public?

Comment: You're obviously struggling to do something very specific. Now you're asking questions about the things that keep you from following down a certain solution path that you have in mind. But I think a much more interesting question would be the one about that original problem you're trying to solve. Surely, there are many other possible solutions to that original problem, than doing some `instanceof` checks.

Comment: @LukasEder of course there are workarounds and different solutions to the original problem. Having worked with jOOQ for a while I mentioned that it's not really suited to on-the-fly modifications, like composing a query from elements based on some conditions, or this one with modificating a query when a condition is to be checked on the query itself. I could give additional details in a more personal conversation. But still I'm interested in motivations for described restrictions.

Comment: Alright, I answered the part about the motivation. It is always the same answer, whenever the complaint about the API *not being suited to on-the-fly modification* surfaces the discussion :) and I'm pretty sure that either 1) The thing you want to achieve can be done in a cleaner way than doing a bunch of `instanceof` checks, 2) Your *real* feature request is much more interesting than a discussion about jOOQ internals. So please, do go ahead and send your detailed problem description to the user group: https://groups.google.com/d/forum/jooq-user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to check the wrapped type of alias field in jOOQ? Something like field.getWrapped() instanceof AggregateFunction.

It is currently not possible get a hold of a field's alias through public jOOQ API, because aliasing, just like any other expressions done with jOOQ `QueryPart` types are all internal API.

There's a low priority pending feature request for this kind of check: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2579

The feature request does not yet describe a well-designed feature, so I'm currently not convinced that it will be added to the API soon.

You could work around this limitation by implementing the [`VisitListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/VisitListener.html) SPI, which allows you to implement callbacks that get called for each `QueryPart` that is visited by the SQL rendering logic. Using a stack machine [similar to the one described in this article](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/06/17/implementing-client-side-row-level-security-with-jooq/), you could then check what expression is contained by an aliasing expression. The `VisitListener` could be triggered e.g. by calling [`DSLContext.render(QueryPart)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#render-org.jooq.QueryPart-).

In fact, it would be interesting to be able to trigger the `VisitListener` SPI without needing to render the SQL string or collect bind variables. I've created a feature request for this:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6735

But in any case, this might be a bit overkill for your real world use-case, which unfortunately, I do not know yet from your question.

> What was the motivation for making this class not public?

Simple: It's internal API. There's no reason why anyone should have access to internal API, which is bound to change at any moment, including between patch releases.

There have been a few complaints by a vocal minority on the [jOOQ user group](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/jooq-user) about jOOQ internals being package private and/or `final`. The complaints were mostly motivated by some short term goals like your suggested `instanceof` check whose motivation you chose not to disclose yet. It is almost always better to discuss the real motivation of a feature request which might translate to an awesome new feature that everyone can use rather than discussing the possibility of opening up just a tiny part of internal API for overriding. This sort of overriding is akin to simply patching the original source code and building the fork oneself. It might work in the short term, but for the community and the library itself, it is not a good solution because it only increases the maintenance pressure from a backwards compatibility perspective while not adding any value in general.

In that sense, it is a very very good idea to close down library internals by making them package private. Likewise, you do not have access to Java 8's `Stream` implementation classes, because, well, you shouldn't have such access.

More details about this API design motivation here:
https://blog.jooq.org/2017/03/20/the-open-closed-principle-is-often-not-what-you-think-it-is/

Comment: Thank you, Lukas. I always appreciate your thorough answers.

Comment: @Scadge: Thanks for your nice words! And I'm really looking forward to your more detailed description. Very curious about that use-case!

Comment: I'm currently investigating a few different solutions, will come back to jooq-user forum when I better define my idea :)